# How can I copy a table from Derby DataBase into Swing application applet?

Tags: java, database, swing, database-design, derby

Is there any way of loading complete table from DB into a Swing Cardlayout's Jpanel?
My try was by creating a label for each line, but then things looked very faulty as if I had a column that had more text it was shifting the next column text and whole thing is messy.

Any ideas?

**Note:** I found that there is something called Jtable, and it might help, but I do not know if I can do that my table cells will be transparent and will reflect a background image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JTable will definitely help, but there's a bit of a learning curve. You'll want to learn how to create and populate a [TableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html), and then pass that model to an instance of JTable.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to build a simple database browsing tool, you might try using SQL Squirrel: http://www.squirrelsql.org